# How to get raw file data from node-fetch calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

Supposing I have an endpoint like `https://someurl.com/myfile.mp4`. I want to fetch the mp4 file and insert its raw data into a string in order to calculate the sha256 of the entire file content. How to do this using the node-fetch library? All the examples I found on the internet assumes that an json object is returned from the query, is it always the case and I should use another library? Here's an example code:

```
let urlFinal = 'https://someurl.com/myfile.mp4';
let videoFile = await fetch(urlFinal, {method: 'GET'}).then(res => { return res.blob() });
console.log('videofile: ' + videoFile) // prints out: videofile: [object Blob]
console.log('videofile: ' + JSON.stringify(videoFile)) // prints out: videofile: {}
calculateHash(videoFile)
```

I also didn't found anything about the `blob()` function and object in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). So what is the simplest way to reach the file data in this case? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download video raw content in memory like this:

```
const downloadNew = () => {
    http.get(urlFinal, (res) => {
        const { statusCode } = res;
        const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

        let error;
        if (statusCode !== 200) {
            error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
        } 
        
        if (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            res.resume();
            return;
        }

        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        let rawData = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
        res.on('end', () => {
            try {
                console.log(rawData);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e.message);
            }
        });
    }).on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
    });
}
```

You can do it using node-fetch as well as with nodejs native code. I'll demonstrate both ways of downloading content in Nodejs (with/without using third party Libs):

Download using Node-Fetch library:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const urlFinal = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4';
const util = require("util");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const newFilePath = "/home/amulyakashyap/Desktop/download/BigBuckBunny.mp4";

const downloadUsingFetch => ()=>{
  fetch(urlFinal)
      .then(res => {
          const dest = fs.createWriteStream(newFilePath);
          res.body.pipe(dest);
      }).then(()=>console.log("finished"))
      .catch(console.error);
  }
```

Download using Native Nodejs (without third party lib support):

```
const downloadUsingNative = function(cb) {
  let file = fs.createWriteStream(newFilePath);
  let request = http.get(urlFinal, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
     console.log("done")
      file.close(cb);

    });
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    fs.unlink(dest);
    if (cb) cb(err.message);
  });
};

const downloadUsingNativePromisified = util.promisify(downloadUsingNative);

downloadUsingNativePromisified().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: but i don't need to write the file to disk, i just need to get its data as string, in memory. isn't another way where I dont need to create a file with `fs`?

Comment: @Fabiotk I have updated the answer, please check the very first approach in the answer. I hope it works for you. Also refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354719/in-node-js-how-can-i-write-to-file-chunks-uploaded-from-a-video